# Using AWK to skip first line and pattern match for the rest

Tags: shell, awk

In the following text, I would like to skip the first line and put $ in front of lines starting with Part1. I have included my script, but it not working. Can you please help?

```
Input
------
Intro
Part1 Yellow
Part2 Red
Part3 Green
Part1 Yellow

Desired output:
--------------
$Part1 Yellow
Part2 Red
Part3 Green
$Part1 Yellow

Code:
awk 'NR>1 {$0~/Part1/($0="$ "$0)}1' myfile

Error:
awk: Syntax error  Context is:
>>>     NR>1 {$0~/Part1/(       <<<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk`. Simple explanation would be, its skipping 1st line(`FNR>1`) condition AND its checking if a line starts with `Part1` then its adding `$` in front of current line's value. Then mentioning `1` will print the edited/non-edited line.

```
awk 'FNR>1 && /^Part1/{$0="$"$0} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, appreciate your prompt answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the first line and not to print it, I'd make this change in your code:

```
awk 'NR>1 {if ($0 ~ /^Part1/) $0="$"$0;print}' file
```

or more concise:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {if (/^Part1/) $0="$"$0;print}' file
$Part1 Yellow
Part2 Red
Part3 Green
$Part1 Yellow
```